# How to check if a real number is a natural number in pascal?

Tags: pascal, division

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to write a simple program that will calculate all the dividers of a number. After doing a division I want to write only the dividers that give me a natural number. I can't think of a way to do it.

Loop with dividing the number

```
For i := 1 to x do
    Begin
        D := x div i; 
        WriteLn ('Divider', lp, '. ', x, ' : ', i, ' = ', D); 
        lp := lp +1; 
    End;
```

Comment: Have you made *any* effort at all to do this yourself?

Comment: @KenWhite I know it might be simple, but like I said, I'm very new to programming and I don't know how to check it. If I would have figured it out by myself, I wouldn't have posted this question.

Comment: My point is that this is not a tutorial site. If you can't get started, ask your instructor for more help or find a tutorial page. We're not here to write your code for you; we're here to answer specific questions about problems you're having with *your code*. You should have at least a basic attempt at a program with variable declarations and code that does division, with the question now being how to tell if it's a natural number. I don't see that program here in your question.

Comment: @KenWhite I have the program done, I'm just missing the part where I have to check if a number is natural. I didn't think that posting a simple loop is a requirement. I've added it to my question. I didn't ask for anyone to write the code for me, I just asked how to check if a real is a natural number.

Comment: Testing if a real is a natural number is theoretical impossible, since it does not contain an exact result. You cannot distinguish a natural number from a non-natural number that is very close to a natural one.  *Luckily, you do not need to do that.* `div` does not return a real, but the result of the division rounded down to the next natural number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint - rather than checking whether the result of x div i is natural, why not check whether x is divided exactly by i? Meaning that x mod i should be 0.

Comment: I was thinking about it for a while, and I came up with this: D := x / i; D2 := x div i; if D2 = D then do...   Seems to be working fine. D is real and D2 is integer. But thanks for the answer, might be useful for the future :)

Comment: I am glad that you have figured it out, though I still recommend you use the mod operator. As you move away from Pascal, you will see that not all languages behave like this with divisions and comparisons between reals and integers.

Comment: @MDoubleM: Listen to the advice. Use mod, do not compare integers with floating point values. Checking if x mod i = 0 is the proper way to do this.